# ASP.NET Core - ModelState.ValidationState is unvalidated for some properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-binding

I have a controller that takes some model `MyModel` in a POST method. Inside of the controller method, there is a check:

```cs
[HttpPost("mymodel")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff(MyModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     // early return with errors
   }

   // ...
}
```

With some specific data, `ModelState.IsValid == false` and `ModelState.ErrorCount == 0`. The reason why it is invalid, is that some properties end up with `ValidationState == Unvalidated`, making the whole model `Unvalidated`, thus not valid.

How can I find out what happens? Why would some properties be just `Unvalidated` instead of having an error? Some of the `Unvalidated` properties have validation attributes, some don't, but other properties that end up as valid also follow the same pattern - some have attributes, some don't.

Any help with a digging direction would appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to show the html form as well, especially inputs, thanks

Comment: Can you share your Model and View? Is the data passed from your view to the controller consistent with the data type of `MyModel`?

Comment: You can log all the errors and check what is the problem - Here a snippet - `var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y=>y.Count>0).ToList();`

Comment: Sadly, I cannot share the html or the model itself - model is over 400 lines, plenty of properties and is central to the app. I just need a direction to figure this out on my own.

Comment: @Anuraj like I said, the error count is 0, this does not show anything.

I figured I will set log level to `Trace` and maybe find something there, but it seems that model binding doesn't log too much, I just get the endpoint hit, endpoint started, endpoint executed

Comment: Are you using any custom validation objects? Or you're using the default ones?

Comment: if there is any validation on a given property, it's only the default ones. Sadly, trace logging of validation only says: validation started, validation result: unvalidated. The problematic properties are bound correctly, according to logs. Many people say something about malformed HTML, what should I look for? Not closed tags, typos, weird labels?

Comment: You don't need to share all of the model and view, you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is enough. @Krzysztof Skowronek

Comment: yeah, I tried to make that, but there is too much going on in there. Also, I'm not looking for a solution, I'm looking for a hint where to look next, because all my leads just ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that in our case the properties in `Unvalidated` state were defined in base class, some of them were get-only. When we called the endpoint, the POST data had values for the get only properties, because model came from GET endpoint.

Now, in the UI we removed one element from a list, making the previously calculated values out of date. The difference was cause of the error - it went away when stopped sending the properties.

I tried to create a repro, but it works on minimal example, and I wasted enough time on that. Maybe someone will find that helpful. Here is what I thought would recreate the problem:

```cs
public class Class1
{
    public List<Class2> Objects { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Class2> Objects2 => Objects.ToList();
    public IEnumerable<int> ObjectsIds => Objects.Select(x => x.Id);
}

public class Class2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("/post")]
    public ActionResult Post(Class1 arg)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) // in our code this was invalid
        {
            return ValidationProblem();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}

    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();

        var client = application.CreateClient();

        var value = new
        {
            Objects = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1 },
                new { Id = 2 },
                new { Id = 2 },
            },
            Objects2 = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1 },
                new { Id = 2 },
            },
            ObjectsIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        };

        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/post", value);
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The test is green though, and I have no idea why it fails in our case. Both are dotnet 6. I tried putting the get-only properties in derived class, deeper nesting, minimal example still works.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this and tried to get a better understanding on why it was happening and whether there was a way I could resolve this without what I felt was a hack-like approach. But in the end due to time constraints for the time being, I just iterated through the unvalidated items and set them to valid as per below e.g.

```
        foreach (var e in ModelState)
        {
            if (ModelState[e.Key].ValidationState == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Unvalidated)
            {
                ModelState[e.Key].ValidationState = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid;
            }
        }
```

It does the job for the time being at least.

Comment: good to know I wasn't the only one :) still have no idea why they are unvalidated. You also use inheritance for the model?

Comment: yep.  Interestingly, the issue seems to have disappeared for me after making some considerable changes to the application which included considerable refactoring and revising along side updating some of the libraries to later versions.  As such, I'm unsure specifically what was changed that has resolved this.  I'll pop up further comments if anything comes to light though.